# MongoDB - "added on" timestamp but keep that timestamp when edited

Tags: mongodb, flask

I have a database with a timestamp ("added_on") when the post was added but I am allowing an edit of the post too, so I create a new edition of an edited timestamp ("edited_on"), but the original added on time stamp disappears when the user saves.

The edit function is:

```
@app.route("/edit_question/<question_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit_question(question_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        is_friends = "on" if request.form.get("is_friends") else "off"
        submit = {
            "question_title": request.form.get("question_title"),
            "question_text": request.form.get("question_text"),
            "is_friends": is_friends,
            "created_by": session["user"],
            "added_on": request.form.get("added_on"),
            "edited_on": datetime.now().strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M")
        }

        mongo.db.questions.update({"_id": ObjectId(question_id)}, submit)
        flash("Question Successfully Edited")

    question = mongo.db.questions.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(question_id)})
    return render_template("edit_question.html", question=question)
```

But when I save the edited post, I lose the "added_on" timestamp. It becomes null.

So how do I keep both the original timestamp and the new edited_on time stamp on the same DB collection?

**UPDATE**

Using the code update_one instead, I now have this:

```
@app.route("/edit_question/<question_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit_question(question_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        is_friends = "on" if request.form.get("is_friends") else "off"
        submit = {
            "$set": {
                "question_title": request.form.get("question_title"),
                "question_text": request.form.get("question_text"),
                "is_friends": is_friends,
                "edited_on": datetime.now().strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M")
                }
        }    

        mongo.db.questions.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(question_id)}, submit)
        flash("Question Successfully Edited")

    question = mongo.db.questions.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(question_id)})
    return render_template("edit_question.html", question=question)
```

But it throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[collection].update` is a deprecated method. Migrate your code to using `update_one`:

```
updateQuery = {
    "$set": {
        "question_title": request.form.get("question_title"),
        "question_text": request.form.get("question_text"),
        "is_friends": is_friends,
        "edited_on": datetime.now().strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M")
    }    
}

mongo.db.questions.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(question_id)}, updateQuery)
```

As you see, you don't update `added_on` and `created_by` on edit, as they were already created on insertion.

You can also do some checks to see which properties have changed and supply only the relevant updates in the `updateQuery`

Comment: I keep getting a syntax error with that. I feel like I have done something else wrong now.

Comment: @PaulDavis Can you share the error, please?

Comment: Syntax...  File "app.py", line 133
    $set: {
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I'll edit my comment with the new code that you have shown. I'll give both post and get methods too.

Comment: @PaulDavis You should put "$set" in quotes. I've edited my answer.

Comment: This is good... I can get somewhere. But now I get an error:

 update_one() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update'

Comment: @PaulDavis Well, that's because you're calling 'update_one' for a second time just below that without supplying an update query. Maybe you've added it as a typo.